# Meaning of a wry eyebrow

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> "He knows about Nick's interview tonight, so he leaves and returns with all my favorite foods: Manchego cheese and chocolate truffles and a bottle of cold Sancerre and, with a wry eyebrow, he even produces the chili-cheese Fritos I got hooked on back when I was Ozark Amy."

p.390 Gone Girl by Gillian Flynn.

What information does the adjective wry give about the protagonist's eyebrow? Can someone please try and explain this or perhaps even show me an image of the situation? Thanks.

Comment: He produces the Fritos (a snack food) with a wry expression, probably raising one eyebrow, implying 'Yes, I know they're downmarket compared to the other foods, but I know you have a weakness for them'.

Comment: Another perfectly good answer masquerading as a comment.

Comment: Thank you, Kate Bunting! You are so helpful.